# What does the ordered pair by which Euclidean space is defined consist of?

Tags: metric-spaces, definition, euclidean-geometry, inner-products

The pattern I see is that Euclidean space is an ordered pair, first element of which is in some way related to $\mathbb{R}$, sometimes to $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{C}$, the second one is a function on it.

But the precise elements vary in different sources - [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Euclidean_Space) website alone has two different definitions of the first element: first it says that it's a cartesian space, but right in the next section, it allows it to be instead an ordered tuple - vector space, a module. [Encyclopedia of Math](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Euclidean_space) adds to the confusion by using the second case, the "module" definition in the definition of the pair forming Euclidean space.

Second element of the definition is a function, which can be either - according to Proofwiki and Wikipedia, Euclidean metric, $\sqrt{\sum_{i \mathop = 1}^n \left({d_{i'} \left({x_i, y_i}\right)}\right)^2}$ or, as according to Encyclopedia to Math, inner product ${\sum_{i \mathop = 1}^n {{x_i, y_i}}}$ with $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$ and $y=(y_1,...,y_n)$.

Which definition is correct? Surely all of them cannot be, unless definition is different in different branches in mathematics (if that's the case, which branches use which definitions?).

Comment: See [Euclidean space : generalizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_space#Alternatives_and_generalizations) . "Another line of generalization is to consider other number fields than one of real numbers. Over complex numbers, a Hilbert space can be seen as a generalization of Euclidean"

Comment: The issue is that we are speaking not of **the** Euclidean space as a single object, but of a way to characterize a "common pattern" of many mathematical (abstract) structures.

Comment: It's worth mentioning you can derive the distance function $d$ from the dot product $\langle x,y\rangle$.  Let $\langle x,y\rangle = \sum_{i = 1}^n x_iy_i$ be the inner product.  Define $||x|| = \sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle} = \sqrt{\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i^2}$.  This is the norm of Euclidean space.  From this, we can define the distance function $d(x,y) = ||x-y|| = \sqrt{\sum_{i = 1}^n (x_i-y_i)^2}$.  So, we can easily get from the inner product to the metric.

Comment: What about  deducing inner product from the existence of the distance function? Is saying that distance function exists equivalent to saying that the inner product exists?